# SQL and Excel Sumifs conditions

Tags: excel, sumifs

The best way to start off this question is with a specific Example

[image]

There are only three distinct claim numbers. Is there a way to sum up the billed amount for claims containing a revenue code 320 and 300 without summing up claims with revenue code '450'? In this specific example, claimNo U4343 meets the specific conditions I want which comes out to 140. I have huge data sets to work with and I just wanted to know if there is a shortcut to this process in SQL (Access syntax) and Excel 2010?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do this for the SQL part. The way I understand your question, you want to throw out completely any claim number that contains revenue code 450 in any of its rows. Then sum billed column for any claim number that does not. Here is how to do that:

```
SELECT claimno, sum(billed)
FROM T
GROUP BY claimno
HAVING claimno NOT IN
(SELECT claimno
 FROM T
 WHERE revenue_code = 450)
```

However, if you want to sum the billed amount for each claim number and simply exclude the rows containing revenue code 450, you can do that like this:

```
SELECT claimno, sum(billed)
FROM
(SELECT claimno, billed
 FROM T
 WHERE revenue_code <> 450) sub
GROUP BY claimno
```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae94a/6

Comment: Yes, this is it. Thank you so much. You understood my question perfectly. I do want to throw out all claims that contain a revenue code 450. I can use this for SQL Server. How do I implement this with Microsoft Access  2010 syntax?

Comment: Great! The code should work in Access. What error are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

### MS Access

```
SELECT ClaimNo, SUM(Billed)
FROM mytable
WHERE [Revenue Code] <> 450 -- or '450', depends on the column's type
GROUP BY ClaimNo
```

### Excel

You can use [`SUMIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) function for multiple criteria:

```
SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)
```

Assume that the target claim numbers are placed in column *E*, for the 1st claim *U577*, you can apply the below function in column *F*:

```
SUMIFS(C:C;A:A;E2;B:B;"<>450")
```

[image: Result for Excel]